# Does Google Cloud phpMyAdmin Have Generative Code

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-compute-engine

I'm trying to figure out why my install of phpmyAdmin to a ubuntu machine on a google compute didn't work and then did.

I started by installing phpMyAdmin manually on vm1 it worked well.  I used a snapshot of the disk from before the installation of phpMyAdmin and spun up a new vm.  This vm had a different ip but ostensibly the same.  In vm2, I tried the manual install that worked earlier in the day and received a timeout error.  Next, I tried the package installer version of phpMyAdmin.  It wasn't timing out but my root dB password didn't work.  I left my system for ~1, came back, and everything was working again.  What could be vm2's problem?

Comment: Could you provide the timeout error you received for your VM2? or maybe your root dB password didn't work because it is the wrong password due to Input Methods like GB or US keyboard.

Comment: For the manual install that worked correctly on vm1 it was a straightforward timeout error.  The error after the package install mentioned the difference between http/https.  The generative code reference in the title was a joke but I'm starting to wonder if it had something to do with dns registration.  What confuses that for me is I was able to access both vms in the browser with ssl but they did have different ips.  Does phpmyAdmin doe something weird when it contacts the vm? Hope this doesn't confuse anybody more.

Comment: You may also try to configure [DNS Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74297294/does-google-cloud-phpmyadmin-have-generative-code) you can use this GCP public documentation, and if you resolved your main issue here, you can also Post your Answer to help other community for this issue.